# Xamarin android c# combobox equivalence "

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want the equivalence of the combobox for Xamarin adroid. What we often see in applications and that shows prositions in the bottom of the screen you can  scrol the list of item and choose the item

I would like create and display this conrtol in code behind like I do with TextView here:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
TextView tText = new TextView(this);
tText.SetText("Text", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
ll.AddView(tText, lp);
```

Regards

Comment: Add more explanation about your expectation http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

*Spinner* is what you might be looking for, check out https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/spinner/ for detailed description and usage example.

Comment: Yes, It s already good. But How can I add Items in list  from code behind?

Answer (score 0):

the answer of @user2171053 is now Deprecated, as is the Spinner Tool, today i think you use ExpandableListViews:

https://www.google.com/search?q=Xamarin+Android+ExpandableListView&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=c7XDWb7CBo-VwQSDgJHYBA

Anybody, correct me if i'm wrong, at least in what Xamarin respect.